# apache2 python 3.4.3 ubuntu error wsgi no module named

Tags: django, python-3.x, ubuntu, mod-wsgi

I try deploying Django in apache2 with python 3.4, but send error 500.

apache error.log:

```
[Sat May 13 15:56:53.638802 2017] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 3610:tid 140692947613568] AH00489: Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu) mod_wsgi/4.3.0 Python/3.4.3+ configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat May 13 15:56:53.638897 2017] [core:notice] [pid 3610:tid 140692947613568] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sat May 13 15:56:56.622523 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3613:tid 140692834260736] [remote 181.75.140.109:26259] mod_wsgi (pid=3613): Target WSGI script '/var/www/html/reportado-plataforma/reportalo/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Sat May 13 15:56:56.622610 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3613:tid 140692834260736] [remote 181.75.140.109:26259] mod_wsgi (pid=3613): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/html/reportado-plataforma/reportalo/wsgi.py'
[Sat May 13 15:56:56.622646 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3613:tid 140692834260736] [remote 181.75.140.109:26259] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Sat May 13 15:56:56.622842 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3613:tid 140692834260736] [remote 181.75.140.109:26259]   File "/var/www/html/reportado-plataforma/reportalo/wsgi.py", line 12, in <module>
[Sat May 13 15:56:56.622851 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3613:tid 140692834260736] [remote 181.75.140.109:26259]     from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
[Sat May 13 15:56:56.622876 2017] [wsgi:error] [pid 3613:tid 140692834260736] [remote 181.75.140.109:26259] ImportError: No module named 'django'
```

I installed

`sudo apt-get install python3-pip apache2 libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3`

my VirtualHost:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/html/reportado-plataforma/reportalo/wsgi.py
WSGIDaemonProcess reportalo python-path=/var/www/html/reportado-plataforma:/root/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup reportalo
WSGIPassAuthorization On
```

virtualhost directory:

```
<Directory /var/www/html/reportado-plataforma/reportalo>
    <Files wsgi.py>
        Require all granted
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

my environment:

```
appdirs==1.4.3
Django==1.11.1
django-cors-headers==2.0.2
django-filter==1.0.2
django-geoposition==0.3.0
django-location-field==2.0.3
djangorestframework==3.6.2
djangorestframework-gis==0.11.1
Markdown==2.6.8
olefile==0.44
packaging==16.8
Pillow==4.1.1
psycopg2==2.7.1
pyparsing==2.2.0
pytz==2017.2
six==1.10.0
uWSGI==2.0.15
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user that Apache runs your code as is unlikely to have the ability to see anything under the `/root` directory. Usually only `root` can see into that directory. Place your application Python virtual environment somewhere else.

Also read:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html

for the recommended way of setting up a Python virtual environment with mod_wsgi. Use `python-home` as documented and not `python-path`.

Comment: thanks, i create a user and problem solved, I will continue with your advice on python-home